# C preprocessor: How can I disable #error macro?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros

I'm working on a C grammar analysis program. While running C preprocessor, there are some libraries which check the environment and use `#error` to stop compiling. How can I disable them, since I only need the preprocess step to finish?

Comment: You only want the preprocess step to finish?  There isn't a standard way to suppress the effect of `#error`.  Quite a long time ago (maybe even in the previous millennium), the Solaris compiler would complete even if it executed a `#error`; that was, however, a bug in the Solaris compiler — one which I believe is long since fixed.  Maybe you need to look at why the libraries (headers, presumably) generate the `#error` directives and set things up so that they are not executed — so that the preprocessor doesn't encounter errors.

Comment: Can you just modify the files and comment out the `#error` lines?

Comment: Won't the results of your analysis be *wrong* if you ignore #errors? The #errors are clearly not triggered by the real compilation process, so there must be something different between your analyzer and the real compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to disable them?  They are outputting an error and stopping compilation for a reason.  The only way I know to disable them is to modify the source code and remove them.

Comment: Not OP, but 3rd party libraries that check for certain compiler versions and output an error if you use another compiler. A lot of static analysis tools pose as compilers. I don't want these specific #errors and I also don't want to modify 3rd party headers (since then you need to redo it on every update).

Comment: My use case is I need only need the macros defined in those files but the #error directive prevents `cpp -imacros sys/some_header.h` to get them

Answer (score 0):

If an `#error` preprocessor directive is being executed, that means preprocessing is done.

If the directive is conditional  (e.g. an error only emitted if some set of conditions are met, such as in a `#ifdef SOME_MACRO` - `#endif` block) then the way to avoid it is to ensure the relevant conditions aren't true.

In the (extremely rare) situation that the `#error` is unconditional, then presumably the intent is to stop preprocessing immediately.  Rather than disabling it, the solution is to avoid it (e.g. not `#include` the file which does that) not to disable it.

If you only want to run the preprocessor, then the presence of `#error` makes no difference.   Most compilers either have the preprocessor as a separate program, or have an option (e.g. "gcc - E") that causes compilation to stop after the preprocessing phase.